# apollo-link-state not practical with HUGE data sets

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-link-state

I'm trying to get this apollo-link-state to work for my app which relies on a tremendous amount of nested data. I went this route because front loading all that data takes 20seconds, can't have that. So, i figure to load the bare minimal, and then when a user moves thruout the site, I make the necessary calls and merge it into cache.

Here is the problem. I have to define A DEFAULT data set, AND then I have to create the query for it. Is it really necessary to have a query that expects hundreds of data points, THEN define defaults for all of that.....That is soooo much work just to cache data. Every example I see about apollo-link-state is some silly 2 liner and everyone says "see how easy it is..", yeah, but its wholly not practical UNLESS I am missing something here... what are my options...

So, in my client file, I have

```
const defaults = {
    id: '',
    session: {
      id: '',
      user_id: '',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      admin: '',

    advertisers: {
      /// bunch of values
      administrators: {
        // bunch of values
        permissions: {
           // bunch of values
        }
      }
    },
    products: {
      automotive: {
        // bunch of nested object with values
      },
      sports: {
        // bunch of nested object with values
      },
      entertainment: {
        // bunch of nested object with values
      },
    },
};

const resolvers = {};

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const stateLink = withClientState({ cache, defaults, resolvers });
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, new HttpLink({
    uri: `${config.url}/graphql`,
    credentials: 'include'
  })]),
  addTypename: true,
  dataIdFromObject
});
```

That defaults is not even half of what I need.

Then in my query, I call what I am willing to front load, then add @client to those I will "merge in on the client" side... BUT, now I have to manage two seperate files to achieve and there is alot of redundancy.. But my query is just a GIANT file because I need to cache everything there because as a user moves thru the site, they need different items from different parts of the query.

So, when I run this, it errors out because it expects EVERYTHING to be in that defaults that is in the SESSION_QUERY... keeping two seperate, gigantic, needs seems so......ugggggh. I must be missing something.

```
<Query query={SESSION_QUERY}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => {
    // render appropriate component depending on loading/error state
    console.log("IN QUERY:::: ", loading, error, data, this.props.client.readQuery({ query: SESSION_QUERY }));


    return null;
  }}
</Query>
```

Now, I am getting errors because the "default" needs literally everything in it... I just don't see how this is maintainable.... apollo couldn't think of a better way? What am I missing?

Comment: You said "when a user moves throughout the site, I make the necessary calls and merge it into cache" -- where are you fetching all this data from? One or more REST endpoints?

Comment: graphql mutations & other queries.. so the goal is to have a subset of data loaded so I can load the site and have bare minimum data. THEN, as a user moves thru different parts of the app, I will QUERY additional items.. merge that into the session. Then if they fire mutations, I merge the results of that mutation into the session etc..... This would be sorta trivial in Redux, but.. in apollo..maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Apollo manages your cache for you for queries and mutations, so there's no need to utilize `apollo-link-state` on top of it. `apollo-link-state` is meant to let you utilize the same mechanism for app state that's specifically not related to your queries and mutations

Comment: but does it manage the cache in a "state machine"? If not, then I need a mechanism for that right? So, lets say I query a product and ALL its data.. I need that data on another part of the site, maybe with a bunch of things the user "clicked on and mutated etc..", how do I then access that data on another part of the site? I can't wrap everything in nested <MUTATION...<QUERY... wouldn't it be better to just wrap everthing in ONE QUERY, a session or "state machine".. I mean, there must be a disconnect.

Comment: I use to wrap all my components with the SESSION query, and yeah.. it would cache because I front loaded everything and when I "mutated" it got the update. great... BUT, now I totally bare-bones it.. so HOW do I have get it back in piecemeal into this same "SESSION".... that was the source of truth.. I want to maintain that.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be better to wrap everything in ONE QUERY" -- maybe in some respects, but that's not how these libraries are intended to be used and there's performance drawbacks to that approach (everything rerenders any time your "session" is updated).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188448/discussion-between-daniel-rearden-and-james-emanon).